# A Capital Cipher

Tags: code-golf, string, cipher

Your task is to decipher a non-empty string consisting of printable ASCII characters in the range **[32..126]**.

Reading the string character per character:

- each time you encounter a letter in lowercase, associate it with the next letter in uppercase, starting with **'A'**
- each time you encounter a letter in uppercase, replace it with the letter in lowercase it's associated with
- other characters do not require any special processing and are just left unchanged

### Example

For the input string `"endlAsEBAEE"`:

- Associate `e` to `A`, `n` to `B`, `d` to `C` and `l` to `D`
- Replace `A` with `e`
- Associate `s` to `E`
- Replace `EBAEE` with `sness`

The final output is `"endlessness"`.

### Clarifications and rules

- The input string is guaranteed to contain each lowercase letter at most once. All further instances will be replaced with the corresponding capital letter.
- The input string is guaranteed to be valid. (You will not encounter a capital letter that is not yet associated with a lowercase letter.)
- Once a capital letter has been associated to a lowercase letter, it may or may not be used later in the string. For instance, `C` and `D` are not used in the above example.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

### Test cases

**Inputs:**

```
abcd
honk! ABCD!
abrAcAdABCA
endlAsEBAEE
helCo wDrCd!
dermatoglyphics
progBamFinD AuzJles & cCdL DCKf
sphinx of black quKrtz, jOdge my vGw. K NODLM IPGZE HGF SOWBA GYVP QCV JKRX TGU.
petBr AiABD AEckBd a ABFG of AEFGlBH ABAABDs. hJw mIny AEFGLBH ABAABDM HEH ABCBD AEABD AEFG?
```

**Answers:**

```
abcd
honk! honk!
abracadabra
endlessness
hello world!
dermatoglyphics
programming puzzles & code golf
sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow. a quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
peter piper picked a peck of pickled peppers. how many pickled peppers did peter piper pick?
```

Comment: I think the inverse of this task - encoding a string of lowercase + punctuation -  would also make an interesting challenge.

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
fØaØA,y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY0/UoNAHEZ7TvHZWGW4gvPbZVkCROK/aOwIC4FkgQiJSEobr5BDWKaz5CR6ESRxxu775s28t4q1bvs@6Q5hd6BR239/HbuPn/fPed@Hi0gZ4aKiiBQxTkZcKE21YCSEkcaal2isiqsLY1OVSxbmdlZYoN3e1XGNS0Rc@bC4lxj1Js2KN5QJFjqM1njZedV2P8IqUMsYeYtX2ZjwcB1Y/gTjqXwWcKSNu@CREeR8NsUNn8H1bp9wLx9MYxNvWQXKiA1BEa2ZQghitjw1SNhSM2f4NPDaROo2yMdFeyb@P5nAEafNz5I/lS2vfgE)

#### How it works

```
fØaØA,y  Main link. Argument: s (string)

 Øa      Yield the lowercase alphabet.
f        Filter; keep only characters that appear in the lowercase alphabet.
          Call the result r.
   ØA    Yield the uppercase alphabet (u).
     ,   Pair; yield [u, r].
      y  Translate s, using the substitutions in [u, r].
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

Code:

```
AÃAus‡
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f8XCzY2nxo4aF//8XFOWnOyXmumXmuSg4llZ55aQWK6gpJDun@Ci4OHunAQA)

Comment: Your answers put me to shame usually `ʒ.l}Aus‡`.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 62 bytes

```
s=>s.replace(/[A-Z]/g,c=>s.match(/[a-z]/g)[parseInt(c,36)-10])
```

Each capital letter is converted to its base 36 value, less 10.

We then match on the lowercase letter that's at that index.

```js
let f=

s=>s.replace(/[A-Z]/g,c=>s.match(/[a-z]/g)[parseInt(c,36)-10])

console.log(f('abcd'))
console.log(f('abrAcAdABCA'))
console.log(f('endlAsEBAEE'))
console.log(f('helCo wDrCd!'))
console.log(f('progBamFinD AuzJles & cCdL DCKf'))
console.log(f('sphinx of black quKrtz, jOdge my vGw. K NODLM IPGZE HGF SOWBA GYVP QCV JKRX TGU.'))
console.log(f('petBr AiABD AEckBd a ABFG of AEFGlBH ABAABDs. hJw mIny AEFGLBH ABAABDM HEH ABCBD AEABD AEFG?'))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 36 bytes

```
JKr1GVQI&}NG!}NH=XHNhK=tK)p?}NJ@_HNN
```

[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JKr1GVQI%26%7DNG%21%7DNH%3DXHNhK%3DtK%29p%3F%7DNJ%40_HNN&input=%22sphinx%20of%20black%20quKrtz%2C%20jOdge%20my%20vGw.%20K%20NODLM%20IPGZE%20HGF%20SOWBA%20GYVP%20QCV%20JKRX%20TGU.%22&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
JKr1GVQI&}NG!}NH=XHNhK=tK)p?}NJ@_HNN
JKr1G                                  Let J and K be the uppercase alphabet.
     VQ                                For each character in the input...
       I&}NG!}NH         )             ... if the character is lowercase and not
                                       yet in H, ...
                =XHNhK                 ... add the letter and the next uppercase
                                       letter to H...
                      =tK              ... and move to the next uppercase letter.
                          p?}NJ@_HNN   Print either the next character or the
                                       letter it represents.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Ñ·í=Üò°f1èb
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=a5faa13d9a95f866318a62&i=abcd%0AabrAcAdABCA%0AendlAsEBAEE%0AhelCo+wDrCd%21%0AprogBamFinD+AuzJles+%26+cCdL+DCKf%0Asphinx+of+black+quKrtz,+jOdge+my+vGw.+K+NODLM+IPGZE+HGF+SOWBA+GYVP+QCV+JKRX+TGU.%0ApetBr+AiABD+AEckBd+a+ABFG+of+AEFGlBH+ABAABDs.+hJw+mIny+AEFGLBH+ABAABDM+HEH+ABCBD+AEABD+AEFG%3F&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 79 bytes

```r
function(x){s=utf8ToInt(x)
s[j]=s[s>96&s<123][s[j<-s>64&s<91]-64]
intToUtf8(s)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZBbb4JAEIXf@RWnPigkamLbmJqIzS4CKlptq/ZifUAuiuJi2aV4ib/dgk36NPPNmTknmfjiqxc/YY4IIibvlRNXE@E/jKMuExlKfLaeq3zGW416kTdrt3fzWTZqVnirfp8NGrV5pX4/lwImxtEkO5S5cr6kUexyqHBkqWAvHLdQzmtMHOISqpEcPeaGhOuU6HqOKy/UIqTtWHNvct7F0ZLaWyNgbZDk2As9jiIcze2jrVl@vsJ3q4DtEflYhLazwXdixeJYxnroLj1sD/gx0yosPA3b/QG6I/NTR8c08Dp8owTmx3SEZ22KnvXyjrE5qV5jPUFjkIDQLFZ3NtSFDUINM48humGGtJMxyXRexaqXYttlh6vS/1cG6Oh5r11N/qwM8zH3P4lVwEE8LqBxJNzzk/BcUCQ/iuUUAcP1c8pJAhxbyL6cKuXSFysp0vnyCw)

Comment: Very nice ! You can probably save a few bytes by using `scan(,"" ` to make it a full program instead of a function, apart from that I am struggling to find any improvement...

Answer (score 2):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) with `-p`, 27 bytes

```perl
eval"y/A-Z/".y/a-z//cdr."/"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZDLTsMwFET3@YpLFqzamA1rdO04bpuUFCgFykNyY7cJdR44fZAifp2QFondjI50RppKW3PZtnonjdsQ7M@J6zVE9g@EJMp6LnHbVi4S5ciFxQQVUoaOLpTBmlPk3Em1YSXsfcvUmVPZckVlHmSFD7g9jIyu4RwSpiLwWbh06irNik8ol7AwMlnDxza0m0MP3mO10pA3sBN7D0K4jv1oDMOJmHMYiADu4geKIJ5mE7hhMxiFt48wFfeeU@kNtYAZ0m6QJ2uqQALSQBw3kAfC0EHXseO1B@loD/mwaE4k@idjGPBjZifJnyoQVz9ltcnKom77VUCe37pPXurXr4veN/kF)

-2 bytes thanks to [@breadbox](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4201/breadbox)!

Comment: Save a couple of bytes by replacing the `s///gr` with `y///cdr`.

Comment: @breadbox of course, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), 37 bytes

```
00000000: 2505 cd03 8030 0176 fe7b 300c fe61 3011  %....0.v.{0..a0.
00000010: fe5b 3004 fe41 3003 ff18 e7d6 414f 0a18  .[0..A0.....AO..
00000020: f777 2318 f3                             .w#..
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYzNjoJAEITvPkUlxmunhwGGeNnMqKBmN/sAnhCY1Yi6WY1GfXi2wZ@jdarqqv6uCf/sa980/NAQQcQRipI1EtYMViaGr8wSmrkQFytxSgEDEjGd6MZEOVPvTlDC8FXU7UNxYbsXmvcqQWXKGKEKPTiXCFrIr@WWRPabnoygZRhjEGhZeY13onOfqGl@q6P7g11bN4adFBtXIod1aYa9l0Oa1W4q2Up/IKzmZ2xnu0vXfL6aL0wnrR91kDsqzT7@AQ)

z80 does pretty good at this! Here is a disassembly:

```
  dec h         ; HL = cipher write pointer
  dec b         ; BC = cipher read pointer
                ; meaning of 'A'..'Z' is written to $ff00~$ff19
next:
  call $8003    ; getchar
  jr nc, ok     ; not EOF?
  halt
ok:
  cp '{'
  jr nc, other  ; a ≥ '{'
  cp 'a'
  jr nc, lower  ; 'a' ≤ a ≤ 'z'
  cp '['
  jr nc, other  ; '[' ≤ a ≤ '`'
  cp 'A'
  jr nc, upper  ; 'A' ≤ a ≤ 'Z'
other:
  rst $38
  jr next
upper:
  sub 'A'
  ld c, a
  ld a, (bc)
  jr other
lower:
  ld (hl), a
  inc hl
  jr other
```

We point both HL and BC at the `$ff00` range with `dec`, and use `rst $38` as a short alternative to `call $8000`, but otherwise there isn't much trickery going on.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 25 bytes

```
~["T`L`"|""L$`[a-z]
$&-$&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3bTsJAFEXf5yu2TSU@SBO/wJyZTqe0RVARL8Sk006BSinYcpHG@OsVMPFt76xkrSrb5KW@aS@vVNz@TKxRHMXWt2VFdjzR3ead2Z2u3WlbnaSG6aSilAxxQSwrTUG15CQlm2eFWGHvVsJcsHW1mnG99PLSBW2boMhqdJAKE8EV4ZTV63lefmE1RVLodIHPbVhtmmt8DMwsw/KAndo7CHE3cKM@ekP1JuErD4@DZ05Qr@Mh7sUYQfjwgpF6ctg62/AKlBM/BmW64AYaxD11apD0VMH946cjrx3Mgz2WvfJwJtE/6cOXpy3Okj@Vp25/AQ) Explanation:

```
[a-z]
```

Match lowercase letters.

```
$`
$&-$&
```

Replace each letter with a degenerate range of itself. (This prevents the later transliteration from treating it as a character class; backslash can't be used because some lower case letters have a special meaning after a backslash.)

```
["T`L`"|""L
```

List the degenerate ranges, but without line separators, and with a preceding `` T`L` ``.

```
~
```

Evaluate the resulting transliteration program on the original input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 78 bytes

```python
lambda s:''.join('@'<c<'['and filter(str.islower,s)[ord(c)-65]or c for c in s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZBJU4NAEIXP@iueF4dUIQer9JBK1Bm2rCZucYk5EAYCCQw4Q8TkzyNglZfu99Xr7lfV@aGIMnFZhf3PKvHSNfeguoQY2ywWGrkjPb9HlsQTHGGcFIHUVCGNWCVZGUhddZaZ5Jrfubi@WmUSPsK2xgKqUzVaNbreX/uc6Ki7pD7llJm0wUDwhCqbUdtuMAoSM0NpSZOfNZzLbMO81ImFBbo/jpJA4Ry@ySewzHHYjKg8isUPshDrxPN3@NqPZXHUsZ3xTYD0gG@3NDDG/cyaTDGcux82Bq6Dp9kro3DfF3M8mAuMxo9veHZfjDY2KJgEjSmrY21/xzg8UOa4TQy1HTdhg5pp7SsD0ahEOhSH1pn8O1MM7Eab7ZG/U457S1bd05NcxqKA0kn/huihVr@q@gU)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 109 bytes

```java
s->{var r=s.replaceAll("[^a-z]","");for(char i=64;i++<64+r.length();)s=s.replace(i,r.charAt(i-65));return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVFNc9owEL3zKzY@dOwCOqUc6pCObGyTACUtbfqRSWeELRuBLLuSDIUMv53KOAVmetCsdt/b3bfzlmRNustkdWB5WUgNS5OjSjOO3rqt/2ppJWLNClGDMSdKwYQw8dICKKs5ZzEoTbQJ64IlkBvInmnJRPb0DERmyoGaChC@jrlp0E4TbiGF/kF1b1/WRILsKyRpyUlMMee29fSLdHfPVseyHDctpB0vDIn1e9cua7dvetdtiTgVmV7Yjuuoc7PNOhLVZKxt1u29cxxXUl1JAcrdH9yjnpNITZVW0H@VCWCReZxYnX/ZohCrK8CeP7g6F8lc4hgnporPRSoSjlXg4SC4aKfcL2AzkH5y0Z9QmRNdZHxbLliszkApi8wjecjEAHC1u@dUwRuI/WQMA3@UnonKNIo/UKQwNxev4Hc1knrXgeU0ySjkW1hHGwQj@DgdjCdw9xD9DGAYhTCbfvMwRD8eH@CT/wj3o8/f4Uv0FV1IoNqTgBn2jIQgXnkJEHN/GNXLcBBG3BuaHBtcIVjcbyC/E9sjMj4hExgG9d8/DmlGhdEH67hk3zhQO1q7XhvwvrHBObkw2ypNc1RUGpXGKM2FnSJSlnxr10zjaDOqVb/94S8)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 105 bytes

```c
C;f(char*Z){for(char*z=--Z,c,*s;c=*++z;putchar(c))for(C=64,s=Z;*z>64&91>*z&&C^*z;c=*s)C+=*++s>96&*s<123;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBtb5swFIU/N7/iFmlRoCRSu6pSxdLKEELbpGv31m0RmuTYhrCAzWzSNFT57ZmdkEjrPmAu5xyfx4Z0U0I2m8BLOmSGpTOxXxMhd3Pd73YnLnEd5ZG@c3JSe@WiMk6H2LZJBf2Lc1f1J55TX12cty9Pr5y63Q5@ObXZoOzgxGxTV5cXbUd9OD177603VcNxty9mv5Yy41XSsSDpxNY7FVt2zPt9iC3Lndj6WHrZR2Ir5tfGMrGYx9xyme2tWwXOeMd@bR1VHQtPCbXc1hHAbrS9rTwTfH4MyA8Gx427U7brPoSnEhFEdQodKiQmmJrXPsQ4zZEKfRSGTcgoTCmunwOO5YGA5UAG9MBjea4lIXN6AFImC1yJNF@Vs4yoJvlWbcKlFKmPi2HGB4AW9Z1mQhtIQMcwCEZJs9mkJC6KjKdQLuq6SQnKIBV5si9Tupq/gEhgmmMyhz@LkaxqF34/0JRBsYLnaNmDEXx8GIzv4fYxmoRwEw3hy8N3H0H08@kRPgVPcDf6/AO@Rt96Df3/WryrXexrha7FWs@0O5ViySERL9ovSgXimUmoZgxyXK@AirR3uDurfAkoQ76@e0jmPtUlyB9GBoXCYZT7N/obaV/1YHa3hOKWr7bO@ODcw01o5mBbsqsaRtf7H8cqTS@zcruSOTOIkuljaoQRcq2UrNS@QQiNwBrxxgGamfnfqmtzjfXmLw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
ØAi
Çị¥¹Ç?€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9qZWxsef//w5hBaQrDh@G7i8KlwrnDhz/igqz///9hYnJBY0FkQUJDQQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

Fork of [Dennis' brilliant Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166573/48934)

```
XQr1G@G
```

[All testcases.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=XQr1G%40G&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22abcd%22%0A%22abrAcAdABCA%22%0A%22endlAsEBAEE%22%0A%22helCo+wDrCd%21%22%0A%22progBamFinD+AuzJles+%26+cCdL+DCKf%22%0A%22sphinx+of+black+quKrtz%2C+jOdge+my+vGw.+K+NODLM+IPGZE+HGF+SOWBA+GYVP+QCV+JKRX+TGU.%22%0A%22petBr+AiABD+AEckBd+a+ABFG+of+AEFGlBH+ABAABDs.+hJw+mIny+AEFGLBH+ABAABDM+HEH+ABCBD+AEABD+AEFG%3F%22&debug=0)